# How do you attach a TableLayout to a button when working with Android?

Tags: java, android, button, tablelayout

I simply want to know how to call/attach/send a table with text to a button. I can get ListView to work fine but I don't know the "idea" behind a TableLayout. All I want it to do is: when the button is pressed it should go to the table and display the text. I'm not looking for anything fancy just simply display the text in a table when the button is pressed. I have a button (named buttonInfo.java)set up on a menu like this:

```
Button btnInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonInfo);
    btnInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.crazyj.peopleinfo.BUTTONINFO"));
        }
    });
```

Here is the table (named infotable.xml)with the text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="1">
<TableRow>
<TextView android:text="Name"
android:padding="3dip" />
<TextView android:text="John"
android:gravity="right"
android:padding="3dip" />   
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<TextView android:text="Number"
android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<TextView android:text="Age"
android:padding="3dip" />
<TextView android:text="32"
android:gravity="right"
android:padding="3dip" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

buttonInfo class:

```
package com.crazyj.peopleinfo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class buttonInfo extends TableLayout{

public buttonInfo(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



}
```

If anyone can answer this please explain what it means! I'm here to learn, not just get answers. And thanks!

Comment: Can you post your buttonInfo.java class

Comment: That's what I need the help with. How do you set up the class to call the table? I can post what I have but it's very ugly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial section better illustrates what you are trying to achieve. Treat the tabs like buttons just to get the concept. It will show you how to create activity classes and invoke them using onClick

(look around step 6)
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

so when you call the activity BUTTONINFO, you have to keep in mind that BUTTONINFO doesn't exactly hold the TableLayout. So BUTTONINFO would be extending activity, since it implements an activity.

Inside your public class for BUTTONINFO you would need

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.infotable);
    }
```

this tells the activity that it needs to set this as the view. "R.layout.infotable" being where it is. (when you made the xml file, there is an android file r that updates itself to include the xml file. so infotable.xml is being called as the view.

Comment: Thanks. I read through it and added some things to the buttonInfo class. But I'm stuck still. I put the new code in the question above. Can't I just "tell" the button to "go to" the infoTable.xml?

Comment: I have updated my answer to better address the question. when i mentioned "r" I am talking about R.java

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks. However I get an error: The method onCreate(Bundle) is undefined for the type TableLayout

Comment: did you change 


public class buttonInfo extends TableLayout


to
 

public class buttonInfo extends Activity

Comment: You, sir, deserve +5000 reputation score. That is ALL I needed. ONE WORD fixed the problem! And thanks for actually helping. How can any n00bs ever learn if people always automatically throw a tutorial in their face and never actually try to answer the question??? Thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome haha

just remember that one word determines what kind of class you are implementing. TableLayout isn't a class it is just a xml tag. In this case you were implementing an activity (they usually call onCreate methods)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial for you. Please have a look

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html

Comment: I've read over it trust me... It doesn't help though. I've also looked up tons of examples but none show how to do what I'm asking.

Comment: This is not a Forum. This is QA site. Read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq . If really want to get the meaning you can join chat. There's a room for Android